# Data import file shifting data with line breaks into separate rows

Tags: r, dataframe, line-breaks

I am having some difficultly importing a text data file into a dataframe.

The last column in the data frame contains a large amount of text some of which has line breaks. The text with line breaks are being shifted into new rows and I can't seem to solve this issue.

I am importing the data using the following:

```
export<-read.delim(file=filename, header=TRUE, na.strings=c("", "NA"), quote = "\"",);
```

Am I missing a parameter that will correct this?

Comment: what is the delimiter for the records (if line breaks are in the fields)?

Comment: It's a table delimited file - \t. It must be mistaking the line breaks in the field as tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the sep variable with whatever your column break is - "\t" for tabs, "," for commas.

`export<-read.delim(file=filename, header=TRUE, na.strings=c("", "NA"),sep="\n", quote = "\"",);`

Comment: I selected read.delim as my file is a tab delimited file and the default argument for sep is "\t". However it's also separating at any new lines?

Comment: It is hard to do any more without a well made example file.  Can you post either your file or an example file?